# Android studio RecyclerView.Adapter custom adapter error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a recycler view and custom adapter to list up array list in recycler view. When I defined a custom adapter `public class NoteDashboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>` (MyAdapter) property it shows in red and solutions says create subclass. How do I overcome with this.

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NoteDashboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList title, date, location;

    public NoteDashboardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList title, ArrayList date, ArrayList location) {
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.location = location;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a list of cardview of my notes dashboard.

Comment: Where is `MyAdapter` defined?